# Multithreading in java static method that move files?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a question about multithreading in java 
so i have a static method that move files and my application is running it as a multithread how did i know that ? :  failed when moving file : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
the methode contains

```
Files.move(
Paths.get(source),
Paths.get(destination));
```

by making the code thread safe it works well

```
 private final static Object lock = new Object();
 synchronized (lock)
 {
    Files.move(
    Paths.get(source),
    Paths.get(destination));
 }
```

the question is : is it a good way? 
is it a multithread method? 
if not what is the solution ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Now the question is why two threads were working on the same file. It doesn't seem that your original problem was related to multithreading, though, because two threads are not two processes. A [mcve] that actually reproduces the situation is necessary.

Comment: i'm using testng and parallel mode is activated multiple tests are passed at the same time that's why two threads were working on the same file if i'm wrong tell me please

Comment: Well, in testing it may well be that it's running parallel JVMs for the tests. Which means your correction is not going to fix it. What you should do is make sure each test uses a different file. If this is JUnit4, you can use a `TemporaryFolder` rule for this.

Comment: so why the problem is not reproduced any more after this modification?

Comment: It could just be luck. Since you have not created a [mcve] we can't really know.

Comment: i have different tests running on the same file every time and i have multiple files ...